# App Store submission shows app icon issues in Xcode 11

Tags: swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode, appicon

I was recently not able to submit the app to Appstore and its showing 3 errors and the thing is i have all the app icons placed in Xcode as you can see in my screenshot correctly but this error comes. I have been trying for many hours to solve this issue. Anyone has idea what is wrong and how to solve? I have included all the icons in my assets folder as you can see . I even checked the dimensions and even deleted assets folders and created new . But still the error comes. How to solve this issues?

> Missing App Store Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store
> Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or
> via iTunes Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta
> App Review
>
> Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key
> 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.abcd.iphone'. Apps
> built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset
> catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For
> more information see
> http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7

---

**XCODE ASSET FOLDER**
[image]

**Added the info.plist screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: You have Info.plist issues. There is no point showing us an asset catalog, that’s not where the problems lie.

Comment: @matt sorry matt I am pretty new to the iOS development so what is the suggested way to solve this . Do I need to add some key in info.plist?

Comment: @matt added the plist screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your asset catalog is in fact part of the app target.

Make sure your build settings point to the AppIcon image set.

[image]

And make sure you don't have multiple asset catalogs with multiple AppIcon image sets, as the build system will not know which one to use.

You should be able to open the built app package in the Finder and *see* the CFBundleIcon entry:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
        <string>AppIcon</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks matt I checked and confirmed that it is already everything the same as what you said . Do I need to add "CFBundleIconName" key in .plist?

Comment: No, if you've got this right it is added during the build.